# NEST v1.0.2 compatibility with elasticsearch 1.4

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am currently using **NEST v1.0.2** with **elasticsearch v1.3.2**.  I would like to upgrade **elasticsearch to 1.4** without having to change my application's NEST dependencies, but I am having trouble finding any information about compatibility of the client APIs with more mature versions of **elasticsearch**.  Does anyone know if these two different versions of the products will be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, yes, but it isn't recommended.  Any 1.x version of NEST should, in theory, be compatible with any 1.x version of Elasticsearch.  However, we don't guarantee this as we do not continually test older versions of the client against newer versions of Elasticsearch.  Any breaking change introduced in Elasticsearch may break the client as well.

However, we do guarantee backwards compatibility between minor versions of NEST.  So upgrading to NEST 1.4 will not break anything in your application, and would also allow you to take advantage of all the new Elasticsearch 1.4 features.

I highly recommend upgrading to NEST 1.4 as well.